# Bot can't mention when tag a role

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So i code a command that the bot will tag a role called @Scrim (ex: A user is finding a @Scrim match). But i realize when the bot send the message people who have the role are not be mentioned, its just a normal message from the bot
Here the code:

```
client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
  if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

  if (interaction.commandName === 'scrim') {
    if (interaction.channelId !== '1039877126205210625') {
      return interaction.reply('Hãy sử dụng lệnh này trong kênh <#1039877126205210625>.');
    }
    const cooldownTime = 15 * 60 * 1000; // 15 phút
    const now = Date.now();
    const lastUsage = scrimCooldowns.get(interaction.user.id);

    if (lastUsage && now - lastUsage < cooldownTime) {
      const remainingTime = (cooldownTime - (now - lastUsage)) / 1000;
      await interaction.reply(`Bạn cần đợi thêm ${remainingTime.toFixed(0)} giây trước khi sử dụng lệnh này.`);
      return;
    }

    scrimCooldowns.set(interaction.user.id, now);

    // Lấy nội dung tùy chọn từ interaction
    const Clan = interaction.options.getString('message') || 'Không có nội dung';

    // Tìm và tag role "scrim"
    const scrimRole = interaction.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Scrim');
    if (scrimRole) {
      await interaction.reply(`Có clan đã yêu cầu 1 trận ${scrimRole} với nội dung: ${Clan}`);
    } else {
      await interaction.reply('Không tìm thấy role "Scrim".');
    }
  }
});
```

I hope that you guys can help me to fix this!

Comment: So your bot is sending the message but no ones being pinged? Your bot probably doesn't have permission to mention the role

Answer (score 0):

Your post is a bit unclear as to what the behavior is. If the bot sends an actual blue highlighted ping, the solution is to give it permissions to ping those roles.

If you meant that the bot only sends the name of the role but not the ping, this is because in order to ping a role or a user, you need its ID to be enclosed inside <@ and > in the message. To achieve this, you have to do it like this:

```js
const scrimRole = interaction.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Scrim');
   //etc
await interaction.reply(`Có clan đã yêu cầu 1 trận <@${scrimRole.id}> với nội dung: ${Clan}`);
   // etc
```

Instead of just sending the name, you send <@1234567891234>, with the number representing the role's ID.